# Delete Express Session when User is Banned

Tags: express, redis

I am using express sessions with redis to build a backend. When I ban a player, I would like to remove his session id from redis by deleting sessions with his/her user_id.

I am using connect-redis with express-sessions.

I know I can do store.all() to get all the sids in redis and check each individual session if its user_id = BANNED_USER_ID, but this seems very inefficient. Is there another way?

Comment: couldn't you just use `store.destroy`?

Comment: I would need the sid of the banner use to destroy the session. sid != user_id